# Toshiba 2,5 hard disk failure - heads defect?

Tags: hard-drive, defective-hardware

My hard disk has problems, it is detected after 10 minutes but there is no way to do read/write. SMART information is also not available.  It makes unusual noises.

I have done a video (https://youtu.be/9y0wctFsCkI) with the open hard drive, are the heads defect? or is it something else?

I have a second one of this HDD can I exchange the heads?

Comment: **Opening the drive's case will damage it.** You need professional data recovery services.

Comment: I want to try it myself, but I need to know if it is a problem related to the heads or something else

Comment: Unless you have access to a very high quality clean room environment and a very expensive set of tools, you cannot service the inside of your hard drive. The platters are spinning at at least 5,400rpm, and more likely 7,200rpm, and the heads are floating above the platters are a distance much less than the width of a human hair. You **CANNOT** service the inside of your hard drive without extremely specialized equipment.

Comment: At this point, your problem is that you have opened the hard drive and powered it on. If it was not destroyed already, it is now.

Comment: The data on the disks is not critical and the disks are very old.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to a very high quality clean room environment and a very expensive set of tools, you cannot service the inside of your hard drive. The platters are spinning at at least 5,400rpm, and more likely 7,200rpm, and the heads are floating above the platters are a distance much less than the width of a human hair.

You **CANNOT** service the inside of your hard drive without extremely specialized equipment.

Well, strictly speaking, you can, but you're not going to be successful, and then you'd have two ruined drives and no way to recover any data.

What you **SHOULD** do is make sure your important data is backed up, purchase a new drive and use it. Then take your old drive apart and marvel at all the shiny parts, because they really are quite pretty inside.

**UPDATE**

I don't normally watch videos linked here, but re-reading your question made me do so, and...

You've already ruined your drive.

The air pressure and humidity inside the drive is carefully regulated to provide the correct operating environment allowing the heads to skim so close to the platters without touching.

By opening your drive you ruined this.

By running your drive while it was open you exacerbated the damage.

It's cool to watch, but your drive is entirely and completely dead now. Not dead in the sense that the motor(s) won't run, but dead in the sense that any data that might have been there which relied on the careful arrangement of hardware and environment is now destroyed.

Dust particles are much larger than the gap between the head and the platter, and they are now gouging holes in the silvery material your data is written on that covers the platters, they are damaging the sensitive head as the platter spins beneath it.

Minute air currents are changing the tensions on your head and platters and pushing these together and apart.

So, forget the part about your data being backed up, and take this as a lesson: **Don't open your own hard drive until you've written it off 100%.**

Comment: No reputable data recovery company will even touch this drive now. The OP couldn't have been any more effective at destroying the drive.